# gparted : error while applying operations

Tags: gparted

I tried to shrink the volume for Windows 7 in Ubuntu,

And I got this error

[image]

Error details:

```
GParted 0.25.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2
Shrink /dev/sda5 from 297.61 GiB to 217.32 GiB  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda5  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda5 (partition)
start: 1001472
end: 625141759
size: 624140288 (297.61 GiB)
shrink file system  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

lvm pvresize -v --setphysicalvolumesize 227872768K /dev/sda5  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

0 physical volume(s) resized / 1 physical volume(s) not resized
Using physical volume(s) on command line.
Archiving volume group "mint-vg" metadata (seqno 6).
/dev/sda5: Pretending size is 455745536 not 624138240 sectors.
Resizing volume "/dev/sda5" to 455745536 sectors.
Resizing physical volume /dev/sda5 from 0 to 55632 extents.
/dev/sda5: cannot resize to 55632 extents as later ones are allocated.
```

========================================

Comment: It looks like gparted messed up and let you try to shrink the volume smaller than its minimum possible size.  Try shrinking it less ( make the final size larger ).

Answer (score 1):

I just found that the hard drive was corrupt

Answer (score -1):

Windows stores some unmovable files near the end of the disk. It is most likely the swapfile.

It is best to use Windows to manipulate Windows partitions. First you need to Boot Windows and turn off virtual memory, then delete the swap file. Then, go to Control Panel --> Administrative tools ---> disk manager and shrink the partition. Next, re-enable virtual memory.

Comment: Windows hs nothing to do with it.  This disk contains no Windows; only an LVM partition.